# Whats this weird images in Thunderbird Mail?

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird, emoji

When I go to check my mails in Thunderbird Mail I see weird shapes floating on my email.

On scrolling up-down those image shapes disappears.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 3]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Looks like emoji in e-mail subjects that TB is not handling very well.